# HTML 301 Redirect in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, http-status-code-301, domain-name

I have 4 URLs that I would like to redirect to my main page.  They are all just common misspellings and I want to have my bases covered so that users can access the site even if they have a letter off.  How would I go about doing this with Google App Engine?

I would imagine that I need a python handler to do the redirects but what would this look like?  Any resources or examples would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use the `self.redirect()` and your request will be handled correctly.

```
class PageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.redirect('/home/', permanent=True)
```

You can also set a custom status using the `self.response.set_status(301)`. I would suggest you reading more in the docs: [Redirects, Headers and Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects).

Comment: so is it fine to do:  self.redirect('http://www.anotherurl.com') and does that count as a 301 redirect?